# Как после отправки contact form7 передать id?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Делаю добавление записи из фронта wordpress средствами CF7.
Подсмотрел скрипт благодаря которому у меня из фронта можно добавить записи, но никак не могу передать значение post_id ?

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'created_post_in_cf7' );
function created_post_in_cf7( $contact_form ) {

  $title   = $_POST['company-title'] && ! empty( $_POST['company-title'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['company-title'] ) : '';
  $content = $_POST['company-product'] && ! empty( $_POST['company-product'] ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['company-product'] ) : '';


  $ars = [
    'post_type'    => 'company',
    'post_title'   => $title,
    'post_status'  => 'pending',
    'meta_input'   => [
      'product' => $content,
    ],
  ];

  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $ars );
  $mail = $contact_form->prop('mail');
  if ( false !== $post_id ) {
    $mail['subject'] = $mail['subject'] .' Создана запись №'. $post_id;
  }
  $contact_form->set_properties(['mail' => $mail ]);
}
```

пытался так, но понимаю что надо сначала получить а потом отправить, а как это сделать?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                Ваша кампания успешно создана под номером <span><? echo $post_id; ?></span>. <br><br>
                                В скором времени с вами свяжется наш менеджер   для уточнения деталей
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Понятно, спасибо</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Тут два вопроса. Отставь один, а второй задавай отдельно.

Comment: @SeVlad ну оставил более сложный для меня

Comment: ID не существует пока пост не создан. Непонято зачем и куда ты хочешь его отправить.

Comment: @SeVlad я это и написал что надо сначала словить после отправки CF7 и потом выдать на фронте, но как вообще нет идей

Comment: @SeVlad в функции он $post_id = wp_insert_post( $ars );  но как дальше передать на фронт?

Comment: Аа.. я сперва не всё понял... Его надо выловить аяксом. Но с этим я не смогу помочь.